# ThreadPoolExecutor intermittently allows uncaught exception through to Main thread

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

In the Runnable tasks that I give to my custom ThreadPoolExecutor, I catch any Throwable. And then instead of throwing the same Exception, I throw a custom RuntimeException. I override the afterExecute(Runnable runnable, Throwable throwable) method in my executor, and as expected, that exception is available to me after execution. It is my understanding that nothing should then happen with that exception, because I've taken care to deal with it. However, intermittently, the exception is being allowed through to the Main thread, which is then printing it to System.err using the Thread.getUncaughtExceptionHandler(). I've validated this by placing the following in my application's main method:

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
    @Override
    public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
        System.err.println("I shouldn't have got here!");
    }
});
```

Now I can easily do nothing in the code above, and prevent the output to System.err, but I would rather figure out why the ThreadPoolExecutor is letting exceptions escape from the tasks I give it. Any thoughts on why this might be happening?

Comment: _the exception is being allowed through to the Main thread, which is then printing it to System.err_ What makes you think it's the main thread doing the printing or do you mean something else?

Comment: That `setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler`: _Set the default handler invoked when a thread abruptly terminates due to an uncaught exception, and no other handler has been defined for that thread._ It's still the same thread that crashed that does the printing.

Comment: You'll need to show us your custom `ThreadPoolExecutor` if you want us to help you find the leak.

Comment: @Pillar I'm fairly certain it delegates to a parent in the thread group, which is the Main thread. I don't know that for sure, but ultimately the result is the same, and is something I want to prevent.

Comment: For your own curiosity, you can verify by logging `Thread.currentThread()` in that exception handler. You can't just take over another thread that might be doing something else at that moment.

Comment: @Pillar You are correct. It is not the main thread. It is one of the threads created by the ThreadPoolExecutor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ThreadPoolExecutor catches and re-throws exception from task:

```
try {
    task.run();
} catch (RuntimeException x) {
    thrown = x; throw x;
} catch (Error x) {
    thrown = x; throw x;
} catch (Throwable x) {
    thrown = x; throw new Error(x);
} finally {
    afterExecute(task, thrown);
}
```

So the exception will be handled by the default handler anyway.

If you want to avoid call to default handler then you can wrap your Runnable with FutureTask which maintains exceptions internally or create own wrapper to be able to handle exception in appropriate place.

Comment: Ah, I did not see that in the code. When I traced through at first glance I was thinking afterExecute was the "termination point" for the executor for a task. Apparently from the source code you're right it just throws it again. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I'm accepting your answer because it illustrates incorrect thinking on my part that an afterExecute call by the executor would prevent the exception from being thrown, which was the core of the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a TPE with a bounded queue and a `CallerRunsPolicy` rejection policy then the runnable will be executed on the submitting thread without any exception wrapping.

That case should be obvious from the exception stack anyway.